# automatic call to removeEventFilter()

Tags: c++, qt

I want to handle events for an object (`a`) by another object (`b`). I call `a->installEventFilter(b)`. If I delete object `a`, the documentation states that the event filter is automatically removed, i.e. object `b` receives no more events to filter for `a`. But I do not know what happens if I delete object `b` first, while `a` is kept alive. The documentation, if I understand it correctly, says nothing about this situation. Will it cause crashes because object `a` will send events to `b`, which is already dead? Or is it a safe thing to do because the event filtering is somehow 'automagically' removed? Or do I have to call `a->removeEventFilter(b)` explicitly, for example in the destructor of `b`?

Comment: What prevents you from trying it?

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to work fine. But I was not sure if this is just coincidence or a rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at Qt source code and here is what I found in QObject:

```
QList<QPointer<QObject> > eventFilters;
```

QPointers are smart pointers that are turned to null when pointed to object is deleted. So to the point - you do not have to call `a->removeEventFilter(b)` explicitly. The Qt manages this under the hood.

EDIT: There is one assumption in this answer - that Qt won't try to filter using null object (even though it knows for sure it was deleted) because I did not find source or documentation for this.

Comment: No, that is the list of the filters installed in *this* QObject, and is used in `installEventFilter` and `removeEventFilter` methods.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Yup, that is exactly what I am saying. If he deletes object that is stored in this list **outside**, the qt will handle nulling it and thus won't call it.